# Status return nagios plugins using sed

Tags: cmd, nagios

I have a plugin in nagios "check_icmp" who return 4 values if the command can ping the demanded host however i got only 1 values if the ping failed so i used the following command :

```
'/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_icmp -w 1000.0,20% -c 1400.0,60% -H 8.8.4.5 -m 5 | sed 's/pl=100%;20;60;0;100/rta=nan;;;; rtmax=nan;;;; rtmin=nan;;;; pl=100%;20;60;0;100/g'
```

and it returns

```
CRITICAL - 8.8.4.5: rta nan, lost 100%|rta=nan;;;; rtmax=nan;;;; rtmin=nan;;;; pl=100%;20;60;0;100
```

instead of

```
CRITICAL - 8.8.4.5: rta nan, lost 100%|pl=100%;20;60;0;100
```

so it works great on the host but if i put this command in nagiosql the current status stay in green "OK" even if the ping failed :

https://ibb.co/LCzvXrV

Comment: Please embed images with the *Image* (*Ctrl+G*) button when you [edit] the question!

Comment: i can't i dont have enough reputation

Comment: Well, you should always be able to edit your own question using the grey link below the question...

Comment: of crouse but i can't embed the image i need 10 reputation at least even for my own question

Comment: Sorry, I was not absolutely aware about [that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268469)!

Comment: it's ok, no problem

Comment: You should not use `sed` command, because you receive exit code from `sed` not from check script (check_icmp) itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that the reason that you're getting an OK despite the fact that the result is "CRITICAL" is because the only thing Nagios cares about is the [return code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#Shell_and_scripts) of the command you ran (also called an exit code). I would guess that `sed` has the last word, exits with return code `0` which means "everything went fine", and it did obviously: for `sed`.

Since you don't explain **why** you're doing any of this, I can't comment on whether this is a good idea or not, but it seems very odd in my mind to include a pipe to `sed` in your check command. I understand that you are sanitizing the [performance data](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/perfdata.html) that is returned by the plugin, but why?

Nagios is built to interpret return codes as the status of your check, that's just the way it is. Whatever issues you are seeing because of this plugins behavior specifically surely can be resolved in another way without running `sed` magic on your checks that you may or may not get intended results from. It's also worth noting that if you're inserting this into RRD files, messing with the order or amount of values may create headaches, so I really wouldn't recommend it.

As a constructive suggestion in the future, please include what brought you to your current solution when asking these questions, as you can never know whether it's actually the best way to resolve your original issue. This is often called an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I'm doing this because I want to have pnp4nagios graphs for my check_icmp output, if I receive a packet lost less than 100% the check_icmp command returns 4 values and the graphs works perfectly ​​but if the lost packet is equal to 100% the command only returns 1 value and pnp4nagios is waiting for 4 values so it fails I have to make a sed to transform the output of check_icmp in order to receive 4 values instead of 1 in case of 100% packet lost ​​to have functional graphs

Comment: If you had asked that question originally instead you would have gotten a better answer than "use sed": the answer is, set "rrd_storage_type" to "multiple". You can read more about this here: https://report.cs.rutgers.edu/pnp4nagios/docs/view/en_US/rrd_convert